# How does a user's rep drop 3K so rapidly?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was looking at the following question on SO
" [How to call addClass() on all body elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532778/jquery-how-to-call-addclass-on-all-body-elements) "

And I noticed the comment stating "A user with 3k should put more effort into his questions ..."
But when looking at Blenders Rep on SO it only shows 231.

I then had a look at the user Reputation Leagues and realized that Blender dropped -3,765 rep for the month of October.

Finally looking at his reputation activity you clearly see that Blender should have much more rep than is shown.

I am extremely curious! Is this a bug? If not how did this happen?

Comment: Something must have changed again in the last hour, because I see him as having 4k rep.

Comment: A clue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111487/ifound-out-that-so-joined-2-of-of-my-accounts-i-had-3-how-to-append-last-one), maybe?

Comment: [For reference purposes only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111487/two-of-my-three-so-accounts-were-merged-how-can-i-get-the-third-one-merged-too).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The user in question has had *nine accounts* merged together by Dori♦.  When a user is merged with their sock, any votes between the two are nullified.

I can't see (without doing some boring investigation and I'm lazy) what votes have been removed because of merging, but I'd assume this has alot to do with it.

Comment: While this is easy to land as the cause, wouldn't the merging of votes also consequently remove the votes from the posts they were on? Which, in essence, is how the reputation would be removed in the first place? More to point, the merge was in November, while the sharp drop in reputation was in October.

Comment: @GraceNote: Good point.  *Lo, if only mods could see all the votes a user cast and received!*

Comment: [Ref](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111487/two-of-my-three-so-accounts-were-merged-how-can-i-get-the-third-one-merged-too/111496#111496)

Comment: I wonder if part of it is also rep-cap issues.  Are those applied retro on merge  too?

Answer (score 8):

The user has offered 900 rep points in bounties, plus the value of question upvotes was [halved at one point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced). That caused that particular to lose a lot of rep (since all his rep came from questions).

Comment: This point of question reputation change was not in october 2011, though. And the 900 rep of bounties (distributed from Nov 2010 until april 2011) don't explain a drop now.

Comment: @Mark, Paulo good points - and weird. Because IIRC, the vote halving was done retroactively and would never show up in the rep graph. Something else must be afoot here then

Answer (score 4):

If my memory is not failing, he had some problems in Stackoverflow and was banished for a long time.

I'm not sure, but maybe the punishment included removal of rep. But most probably he **[spent his rep points in bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194425/blender?tab=bounties)** (he asked a lot of questions).

Comment: Whoops, ignore my previous comment; I happened to just come from a post where the second Blender was involved, and wires got crossed in my head. I tend not to want to call people out by name, but this guy was [held up as an example by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62672/how-should-we-respond-to-persistently-low-quality-question-askers/62685#62685).

Comment: As far as I know, there are no punishments that include direct removal of reputation. There would have to be lots of questions to be removed to cause this

Comment: We do not directly remove reputation from users

Comment: @GraceNote can you explain the discrepancy?

Comment: @JohnHartsock: He has had nine accounts (sockpuppets) merged into his account.  When a merge happens, any upvotes from the puppet accounts get removed.  So if I have 100 rep, 50 of which came from a sock, and that sock gets merged into my account, I'll end up with 50 rep.  Well, actually 1 rep until my suspension ends, then it bumps back up to 50.

Comment: @Won't has this asshat *been* suspended? Because he should be. Shouldn't he?

Comment: Some people never learn.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't Post your comment as an answer as it explains the situation.

Comment: @Pekka: He's suspended for sucking wind, but not for puppetry.  Dori merged the accounts, but I don't see where she did anything else about it.